# Close Android system Date & Time with my Navigation button

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

I have an Device which runs on ICS.

1. When I load my App, First I load the android System Date & Time Settings.
2. I want to Close this Date & Time settings on my navigation button click(Hardware button click)
3. I am getting my button click event.

**4. After getting event this what code shall I write to close  only this system Date & Time settings layout. So that after closing this setting my app still be visible**

Is finish() will work ?

Hope you got my problem .

Comment: I think hardware back button will do automatically.

Comment: No this device is built by our company. Not from any other

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS),1);
```

and then Override onActivityResult and launch ur activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent );

}
```